# How to solve "X^2 - Y is perfect square, X, Y ≤ N" in O(sqrt(N)) time complexity?

Tags: c++, c++17, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization, counting

Given N. Find number of all the integer pairs x, y such that

```
1<=x, y<=N
and x^2 - y is a perfect square
```

the N is large but O(sqrt(N)) will be fine to solve this problem.

I tried to solve this problem like, letting z^2 be the square number

```
x^2 - z^2 = y = (x+z)(x-z)
then let x + z = p and x - z = q;
then x = (p+q)/2 and z = (p-q)/2;
and (p+q)/2<=N;
and p and q should have same parity (both even or odd as (p+q)/2 is integer)
also pq<=N
```

Now I don't know how to proceed from here
or tell me some other method to solve this problem efficiently.

Comment: Maybe you can just iterate on all the pairs `(x,z)`, and return the corresponding `(x,y) = (x, (x+z)*(x-z))`? With x looping from 1 to N, and z looping from 0 to `sqrt(x**2 - 1)`

Comment: Since there are O(n^2) such pairs, how do you expect to even enumarate them in less than O(n^2) time?  Or do you just want to know how many such pairs there are?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Please note that O() denotes an upper bound; surely there are less than `n**2` pairs (x,y) such that x**2-y is a perfect square, and 1 <= x,y <= n.

Comment: If you remove the (upper) bound on y, there are trivially (n\*n + n)/2 such pairs (which is O(n^2)). With the upper bound on y, there are fewer but still at least O(n\*sqrt(n)).

Comment: maybe start with listing the possible perfect squares in range? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-perfect-squares-from-the-given-range/ (second solution) and (then) exclude non-matching (impossible) pairs? just an idea

Comment: Maybe a typo in the problem -- intended to say O(N sqrt(N)) for the solution?

Comment: Re “Find number of all the integer pairs x, y”: Do you want to find all the solutions or to find the number of solutions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a number theory problem, not a programming one. Adding C++ tags does not change that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Im new to stack overflow but it does appear that O(sqrtN) is only possible if _some_ number theory is used.

Comment: @okzoomer it's actually trivial, there is only a single perfect square in the range `](n - 1)^2, n^2]`, and that is `n^2` itself. For `y != 0` that limits your choices in how to choose `x` and `y`.

Comment: @Ext3h
It's not difficult to prove that for x > N/2, the differences in consecutive squares exceed N.
It's also not too hard to see that the (x = sqrtN, y = N) solution that covers most number of squares between x^2 and x^2 - y.
The key is when the difference between squares is smaller than N, figure out exactly how many squares from k to k + N.
In my solution below I iterated through integers from square root of N downwards and count when such number of squares changes.

Comment: @Ext3h oh I see what you mean. No, x^2 can go up to N^2 so x can go up to N. But as mentioned practically you only need to search up to half of N but O(N/2) = O(N). You would need the trick I mentioned or an equivalent to reduce it down to O(sqrt N).

Answer (score 1):

This solution solves the problem in O(sqrt N).

**Rephrasing the problem**

Let z^2 = x^2 - y, z ≥ 0, or equivalently 0 < y = x^2 - z^2 ≤ N

We need pairs of perfect squares under N^2 whose differences are less than or equal to N. By arithmetic series,

1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + ... + (2k - 1) = k^2

That means x^2 - z^2 is a sum of some n consecutive odd integers.

**Counting odd integers**

z^2 + (2z + 1) + (2z + 3) + ... + (2x - 1) = x^2. Apply arithmetic series formula

z^2 + n/2 * (4z + 2 + 2(n - 1)) = x^2

z^2 + n * (2z + n) = x^2

n(2z + n) ≤ N

z ≤ floor((N/n - n)/2)

We are thus able to find the last values of z for which at least n+1 odd consecutive integers are needed for their sum to exceed N.

For each z, the x can be z+1, z+2 ... z+n, for a total of n pairs.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
int N = 99; 
int main(void){
    int z = -1;
    // z = 0 is valid for x^2 < N, so -1 is largest invalid z.
    int count = 0;
    for (int n = std::sqrt(N); n > 0; n--){
        int zNew = (N/n - n)/2;
        // zNew is max z that has n perfect squares from z + 1 to z + n
        count += (zNew - z) * n;
        z = zNew;
    }
    std::cout << count << '\n';
}
```

A version in Java passed these unit tests.

```
(N, count) = (1, 1), (3, 2), (5, 4), (8, 6), (60, 68), (99, 124), (500, 808)
```

Comment: I made some edits to get your code to compile: Put function bodies inside braces, added parameter `int n` to `getMaxX`, changed `findnStart` to return a structure, and changed `main` to print its result instead of returning it. The program prints 0, for N=99. I do not know whether the bug is in the code or the algorithm (or both). Sorry, I am out of time for now and will be out most of today.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for your input! I'll write it in another language see if it works. For some reason i can't see your edits so i just assume i don't have enough points or something

Comment: I did not edit my changes into your answer; I just tried them on my system. I wouldn’t edit the answer until I were certain of corrections.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I deleted the "optimization" and found an off-by-one error.